# OpenCL does not write to passed buffers

Tags: c++, opencl

I can't figure out exactly what is wrong with my code but the vadd function does not seem to work. I think it has to do with to way the kernel is created and how arguments are passed.

The function does not write to any of the passed buffers. Everything compiles.

```
const char *KernelSource = "\n" \
"__kernel void vadd(                                                 \n" \
"   __global float* a,                                                  \n" \
"   __global float* b,                                                  \n" \
"   __global float* c,                                                  \n" \
"   const unsigned int count)                                           \n" \
"{                                                                      \n" \
"   int i = get_global_id(0);                                           \n" \
"   if(i < count)                                                       \n" \
"       c[i] = a[i] + b[i];                                             \n" \
"}                                                                      \n" \
"\n";

int main()
{
    const int N = 1024;
    float h_a[N], h_b[N], h_c[N];

    int count = 10;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        h_a[i] = i;
        h_b[i] = i;
    }

    std::vector<cl::Platform> all_platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&all_platforms);

    cl::Platform default_platform=all_platforms[0];
    std::cout << "Using platform: "<<default_platform.getInfo<CL_PLATFORM_NAME>()<<"\n";

    std::vector<cl::Device> all_devices;
    default_platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &all_devices);

    cl::Device default_device=all_devices[0];
    std::cout<< "Using device: "<<default_device.getInfo<CL_DEVICE_NAME>()<<"\n";

    cl::Context context({default_device});

    cl::Program program(context, KernelSource, true);

    cl::Buffer d_a(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * N);
    cl::Buffer d_b(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * N);
    cl::Buffer d_c(context, CL_MEM_READ_WRITE, sizeof(float) * N);

    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, default_device);

    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(d_a, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * N, h_a);
    queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(d_b, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * N, h_b);

    cl::make_kernel<cl::Buffer&, cl::Buffer&, cl::Buffer&, int> vadd(program, "vadd");
    vadd(cl::EnqueueArgs(cl::NDRange(N)), d_a, d_b, d_c, count);

    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(d_c, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(float) * N, h_c);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        std::cout << h_c[i] << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Side note :** I found it very difficult to learn OpenCL as it seems that even for the simplest task (vector addition in this case) nobody uses the same methods and API functions... Everytime I look for a working example code it is always consederably different from other sources I found...

Comment: Why are you using `int` buffers while `float` in the kernel? Do all functions suceed? Are there no errors?

Comment: Also you should use `cl::Buffer&` in `cl::make_kernel`.

Comment: `int` buffers instead of `float` was a last minute change I should not have made. It is now fixed. I changed to `cl::Buffer&` but it still doesn't work for me